# PHP call SQL Server SP returning data, output parameters and return value

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm a beginner in PHP programming.
I have an SP in SQL Server with input, output and ReturnValue parameters that returns data from an sample table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_PHP]
@in1 int, @in2 int, @out3 int OUTPUT
WITH EXEC AS CALLER
AS
SET @out3 = @in1 * @in2

SELECT * FROM PHP

RETURN @in1 + @in2
```

This is my PHP code

```
<?php
try
{
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=xxxxx,1433;Database=xxxxxx", "xx", "xx");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
die(print_r($e->getMessage()));
}

$query = '{? = CALL sp_PHP(?, ?, ?)}'; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 

$returnVariable = -1;
$inputVariable1 = 18;
$inputVariable2 = 24;
$outputVariable3 = -1;

$stmt->bindParam(1,$returnVariable, PDO::PARAM_INT | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 100);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$inputVariable1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(3,$inputVariable2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(4,$outputVariable3, PDO::PARAM_INT | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 100);

$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

foreach($results as $row) {
    echo $row['PHP_ID'].' '.$row['PHP_Char'].'<br>';
}

echo '<hr>';
echo 'Return value: '.$returnVariable.'<br>';
echo 'Output parameter: '.$outputVariable3.'<br>';

?>
```

If I remove the line in the SP

```
SELECT * FROM PHP
```

and don't read the data received in PHP with following code

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

foreach($results as $row) {
    echo $row['PHP_ID'].' '.$row['PHP_Char'].'<br>';
}
```

I receive the correct values of $returnVariable (42) and $outputVariable3 (432).
But if I read (and show) the data read from the SP, $returnVariable and $outputVariable3 are equal to -1 (the assigned value)

I wanto to read output parameter, ReturnValue and data at the same time.

Is it possible? Where am I wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe resolved changed connection method


$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

The value of the output (or input/output) parameter is accessible when you consume all results returned by the stored procedure (PDO and not PDO versions). In your case you need to move throw resultsets with [PDOStatement::nextRowset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/pdostatement-nextrowset?view=sql-server-2017) to get the values for the output parameters.

**Example:**

I've reproduced your example and next code works for me.

```
<?php
$server = 'server\instance,port';
$database = 'database';
$uid = 'user';
$pwd = 'password';

try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;Database=$database", $uid, $pwd);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    die( "Error connecting to SQL Server".$e->getMessage());
}

try {
    $sql = "{? = CALL sp_PHP(?, ?, ?)}";
    #$sql = "EXEC ? = sp_PHP(?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $returnVariable  = -1;
    $inputVariable1  = 18;
    $inputVariable2  = 24;
    $outputVariable3 = -1;

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $returnVariable, PDO::PARAM_INT | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, PDO::SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT_DEFAULT_SIZE);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $inputVariable1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $inputVariable2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $outputVariable3, PDO::PARAM_INT | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, PDO::SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT_DEFAULT_SIZE);    
    $stmt->execute();

    do {
       echo 'Result set:'."<br>";
       while ($row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
          print_r($row)."<br>";
       }    
       echo "<br>";
       echo "<br>";
    } while ($stmt->nextRowset());  

} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    die( "Error executing query" );
}

$stmt = null;
$conn = null;

echo 'Stored procedure return value: '.$returnVariable."</br>";
echo 'Stored procedure output parameter: '.$outputVariable3."</br>";
?>
```